If possible, fitting multiple claims into one claim
Claims:

a machine that executes Y when A is less than B only.
a machine that executes Y when A equal to B only.
a machine that executes Y when A is less than or equal to B.

Where A and B are user inputs.
Is it possible to fit all three of these claims into one?

What is the goal for this approach?

Having one claim instead of three is more efficient?

What should the scope of the claim be? If you want a machine that does Y for the union of the conditions you've listed it would just be a machine that unconditionally executes Y. If you want a scope that is the intersection of the behaviors, it is nothing (or the empty set) which is not patentable.

well, the machine does nothing in event that A > B?

@Bear No, I mean the set of machines that meet all the recited limitations 1) 2) and 3) is the empty set. You seem to want to have a generic claim that can have these as dependents. That doesn't seem possible.

As a comment says, taken together, these limitations are no limitation. Y executes regardless of the relationship between A and B.
If you mean them to be separate they should be three claims. If they are three claims you can go after three types of machines. In the case that prior art later surfaces that makes one claim invalid, you still have the other two claims.
You get a fixed number of “free” claims and pay for claims above that. Three independent and twenty altogether are covered by the basic filing fees. Going above that with dependent claims isn’t  too expensive.
It is allowed to have limitations in the alternative. A machine that does X when Y happens or alternatively when Z happens can be ok - but if it gets too convoluted you will get a rejection for it being indefinite.
Note - all claims are in the form of a single sentence. It is a matter of form but you can see that your three-in-one falls apart if you try to put into one logical sentence.
